# React Native | Axios post request to Mockable.io API

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I'm building a react native app in which you can order items.

As my currently stands I'm able to fetch/get the following from my Mockable API's

- Items
- Pictures
- Icons

However I'm not able to post to my other Mockable API (ment for posting)

I only have two headers in my post: Accept & Content-type

I'm developing my app using expo

***What do I expect:***

To be able to post to my Mockable API

***What am I getting:***

Unhandeld Promise Rejection (id:0); Error: Network Error

**My POST request**

```
  handleSubmit = () => {

      this.setState({
        orderRestrauntId: this.props.RestrauntId,
        orderValue: this.state.value,
        orderProducts: this.props.products,
        orderTotalPrice: this.props.totalPrice,

      })
     axios.post(
    'https://demo3381137.mockable.io/orders', 
    {
      "orderId": "1",
      "RestrauntId": this.state.orderRestrauntId,
      "orderKey": "F3SAR566T",
      "userId": "1",
      "paymentStatus": "approved",
      "preparing": "approved",
      "orderStatus": "approved",
      "paymentMethod": this.state.orderValue,
      "totalPrice": this.state.orderTotalPrice,
      "order": [
          {
          "product" : "burger",
          "qty" : "5"
          },
          {
          "product" : "pizza",
          "qty" : "5"
          },
          {
          "product" : "fries",
          "qty" : "5"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }
    );

      console.log('submit');
    }
```

Comment: Well, the `https://http://` part certainly does not look promising..

Comment: (*hint: remove the `http://` part*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli , that's a stupid mistake of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabriele Petrioli caught a error in my url `https://http://`, should have been `https://`